# Positioning to bottom of dynamic div

Tags: html, css, positioning

This is what I'm trying to achieve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9xZa.jpg

I tried this

jsfiddle.net/RUSm3/

but as you can see the date overlaps on the image.

So I added left:215px for the date

jsfiddle.net/9aw29/

It looks good but perhaps I don't have an image. How can I get the date back to the far left? I'm trying to achieve this without php.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a div like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="date">today</div>
</div>
```

with this css fragment your date div will be positioned to the bottom right of it's container.

```
.container {
      position:relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 180px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.date {
        bottom:10px;
        position:absolute;
        right:10px;
    }
```

You can verify it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BGzVW/3/)

Comment: Thanks for the sample! However I need to align the date to the left. If I do so it will overlap on the image and if I use `right:200px` to align to the right of the image, it will be too indented when there is no image.

Comment: @sasa: if you provide more of your markup code we can try to adjust the sample accordingly. I just did it this way because I dont know your markup

Comment: @sasa: I can't get it to work with your markup. I am sorry for that. Maybe someone else will be able to help more on this. If was my code, I would change my requirement and put it on the right side :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your markup is, but the easiest solution would be to have the heading, text and date all in one `div` (inside `.entry`), and float the image to the left if it's there. The date would be positioned as you have already done in your example. When there is no image, the entire div will move flush left.

```
<div class="entry">
  <img [...] />
  <div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Entry text</p>
    <p class="date">[Date]</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thx! I tried that but the date will position to the bottom of the div which may have more or less text. If I position it in the entry div it will always be to the far bottom but I don't know how to alter it left, if there is no image.

Comment: To be honest, I'd just go ahead and do it your way, but use php or JavaScript to add a class when there is an image. This class can have the position from the left side via CSS. I know you wanted to avoid it, but using php of JavaScript will make it truly dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with and will probably be a good jumping-off point for you. In short, wrap the two text areas in their own divs, and wrap them in a parent div. Float the parent div to the right and make it's position something other than static. If the position is static, you cannot use the position: absolute attribute with it's children divs.

```
<style type="text/css">
    div.entry{
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        width: 40%;
    }
    img.left{
        float: left;
    }   
    div.right{
        float: right;
        display: inline;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 50%;
    }   
    div.topRight{
    }   
    div.bottomRight{
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }   
</style>




<div class="entry">
  <img class="left" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2010/halloween10-ires.gif"/>
  <div class="right">
      <div class="topRight">
          Some stuff
      </div>
      <div class="bottomRight">
          Some other stuff
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```